# Convert string time to datetime or timespan in entity framework query

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I have stored Time string say `"12:20 PM"` in the database and i want to compare it with current time in linq query (EF). As i can not convert it using Convert.ToDateTime etc because it can not be converted into any sql expression.

I am thinking to write a query like below, but i know this wont help. Please advise.

```
List<CompanyScheduler> companySchedulers = 
    context.CompanySchedulers
          .Where(m => m.IsActive && m.Start <= EntityFunctions.AddMinutes(td, m.TimeZoneOffset))
          .Where(m => (m.LastRun.HasValue && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(m.LastRun) < tdExcludeTime) || (!m.LastRun.HasValue))
          .Where(m => (m.When == (int)When.Daily && (Convert.ToDateTime("01-01-1990 " + m.RecurAt).TimeOfDay < EntityFunctions.AddMinutes(td, m.TimeZoneOffset).Value.TimeOfDay)) ||
                      (m.When == (int)When.Once && !m.LastRun.HasValue) ||
                      (m.When == (int)When.Weekly && m.RecurrEvery.Contains(today)))
          .ToList();
```

Comment: You are best off adding a column, then using SQL to update that column with something sane and typesafe.

Comment: @Aron: I didn't get. Please explain a bit more.

Comment: You main issue is that you have stored your time as `varchar` in your database. Which is a mismatch to the information you are storing. Therefore you want to use `Convert.ToDateTime` to fix this. The correct approach is to ACTUALLY STORE IT AS A DATETIME IN THE FIRST PLACE. That is the whole point of a database schema. Fix your schema, so its sane, then your query will be easy.

Comment: @Aron Ok, If i change the db schema then what should be the query to compare the time portion in EF query? (we can't use Convert.ToDateTime in EF query.)

Comment: Since EF 5, there is support for the datatype of `Time`, which is mapped to `System.TimeSpan`. So simply `.Where(m => m.Start < startTime)` given that `TimeSpan startTime;`.

Comment: @Aron I am using EF 4.1 and i have to compare time portion only not the whole date so m.Start < startTime won't help.

Comment: Given that EF is now at version 6. I can't see why don't upgrade. There is not NICE SANE way to do time with EF. I know...I tried.

Comment: I can't upgrade it to 6 in my old project, it might brake my code.

Answer (score 2):

There is not direct way to 'parse' strings to `DateTime` or `TimeSpan` in *Linq to Entities*, but you can do it using `SqlFunctions` and `DbFunctions` classes:

**For TimeSpan**:

```
DbFunctions.CreateTime(SqlFunctions.DatePart("hh", timeString),
                       SqlFunctions.DatePart("mi", timeString), 
                       SqlFunctions.DatePart("ss", timeString));
```

**For DateTime**:

```
DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(SqlFunctions.DatePart("yy", dateString),
                           SqlFunctions.DatePart("mm", dateString),
                           SqlFunctions.DatePart("dd", dateString),
                           SqlFunctions.DatePart("hh", dateString),
                           SqlFunctions.DatePart("mi", dateString),
                           SqlFunctions.DatePart("ss", dateString));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible below EF 6.x. Either use stored procedure or make all conversions before to link query.

Answer (score 0):

You can load your data in memory (by calling `ToArray()` or `ToList()`) on your collection and use `Convert.ToDateTime`:

```
var date = DateTime.Today;
var areEqual = dataContext.YourTable.ToList() 
        //now the data is in memory and you can apply whatever projection you want
        .Select(x => new{Date = Convert.ToDateTime(x.DateStringColumn)})
        .All(x => x.Date == date);
```

However, this can increase the memory usage if the dataset is quite large. To avoid this use the `Where()` method to load only the records you need.

Comment: This is not what i am looking for. If the database has millions of records then? The where condition is based on that time comparison, so i will fetch only those records which matches the criteria, i can not fetch all records into memory and perform filter.